# Why my Jenkins script hangs on while loop?

Tags: bash, infinite-loop

i am running a Jenkins script for building a Jenkins program and preparing it's environment. 
i posted the section of the script where it hangs. it hangs in the `while [[ "$ENDPOINT_STATUS" != 0 && (( $COUNTER < 5 )) ]]`  line. could anyone please tell me what is the problem ?

```
##############
## wait until config wizard exits
while [ $($SSH pgrep -f /opt/company/grapevine/bin/grapevine_config_wizard | wc -l) -ne 0 ]
do
    echo "Config wizard still running. Sleeping..."
    sleep 30
done

$SSH chmod -v 755 /home/grapevine/.python-eggs || true
$SSH chown -vR grapevine:grapevine /home/grapevine/.python-eggs || true

source $WORKSPACE/tools/dev/quick-sanity/poormans-quick-sanity.sh "$CONTROLLER_IP"

set +e
run_basic_tests "$CONTROLLER_IP"
ENDPOINT_STATUS=$?
set -e
COUNTER=0

while [[ "$ENDPOINT_STATUS" != 0 && (( $COUNTER < 5 )) ]] 
do
    echo "At least one endpoint is not up. Sleeping..."
    sleep 60

    set +e
    run_basic_tests "$CONTROLLER_IP"
    ENDPOINT_STATUS=$?
    set -e

    (( COUNTER += 1 ))
done

if [ "$ENDPOINT_STATUS" -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "Hard fail Failing"
    exit 1
fi

if [ $($SSH service runonce status | grep ERROR | grep config_wizard | wc -l) -gt 0 ]
then
   echo "Config wizard failed with errors:"
   $SSH cat /var/log/runonce/config_wizard*.log
   exit 1
else
   echo "Config wizard succeeded"
   echo "Sleeping while Grapevine services start..."
   sleep 300
   exit 0
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

More of a bash script issue than a Jenkins one.

Do you know anything about the endpoint?  Have you tried testing it manually?  Perhaps there is something going on where it doesn't fail quickly, but leaves the connection "in the process of doing nothing" forever.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning, but I noticed a few things.

1. No `$` inside `(())` e.g. `((COUNTER++))` or `FOO=$((COUNTER++))`
2. Double parenthesis `(())` is not needed for tests or assignments, only operations  e.g. `FOO=$COUNTER` or `if [[ $COUNTER -lt 5 ]]`
3. Use `-a` instead of `&&` inside double brackets `[[]]`
4. For arithmetic, use `-ne` instead of `!=` inside double brackets `[[]]`.  (Use `==`, `!=` for strings)

e.g. ...

```
while [[ $ENDPOINT_STATUS -ne 0 ]] && [[ $COUNTER -lt 5 ]]
```

or ...

```
while [[ $ENDPOINT_STATUS -a $COUNTER -lt 5 ]]
```

[Test Operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22473)

[Arithmetic and String Comparison](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html#EX13)

`http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#EX10`

(third link denied lol)